# Using jquery in xml file in sapui5 fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, view, sapui5

I have a simple problem with my app, i have Image property with empty background, if i click on it should add class to my property
My controller doesn't see classes/id of properties in view.xml document.
Is there a way to communicate with them?

In my view fragment:

```
<Page showHeader="false">
            <content>
                <tnt:ToolHeader>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://nav-back" press="onNavBack" />
                </tnt:ToolHeader>
                <Image id="imageOffice" class="officeImage" width="19.8%" height="26.3%" press="onReservePress"/>
            </content>
        </Page>
```

My controller:

```
onReservePress: function() {
        console.log("Working"); //its ok

        $("#imageOffice").addClass("greenImage"); //its not
    }
```

css file:

```
.greenImage {
background-color: rgb(174, 243, 231);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native function to access your element

```
onReservePress: function() {
    console.log("Working"); //its ok

    this.getView().byId('imageOffice').addStyleClass("greenImage");
}
```

This will still use jquery though :)
I think you can optimize this by using the event source (and prevent ID usage):

```
onReservePress: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("Working"); //its ok

    oEvent.getSource().addStyleClass("greenImage");
}
```